# DrawerItem class missing in flutter Dart

Tags: dart, drawer, flutter

I am currently learning to develop apps using flutter, I saw a video where DrawerItem class is used and when I type DrawerItem it shows me an error stating that the class is missing. DrawerHeader works fine.

Could anyone help me with what to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DrawerItems were deprecated in favour of [ListTiles](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html) and [AboutListTiles](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/AboutListTile-class.html). You can find information about the drawer in the [docs](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Drawer-class.html). This is the first place to look for information like this ;)